# Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class java.lang.String

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I'm trying to make a simple query. I created a customizedPlaceRepositoryImpl class that implements customizedPlaceRepository.
The problem is that when I try to invoke the endpoint in the browser it returns me "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find PersistentEntity for type class java.lang.String!"
How can I cast the getResultList() to String

customizedPlaceRepositoryImpl

```
public class customizedPlaceRepositoryImpl implements customizedPlaceRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public List<String> findAllDistinctPlaceName() {
        String qlQuery = "SELECT name FROM place";
        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(qlQuery);
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Object o: query.getResultList()){
            result.add((String)o);
        }
    return result;
    }
}
```

customizedPlaceRepository

```
public interface customizedPlaceRepository {
    List<String> findAllDistinctPlaceName();
}
```

Stack trace

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class java.lang.String!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentEntities.lambda$getRequiredPersistentEntity$2(PersistentEntities.java:96) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentEntities.getRequiredPersistentEntity(PersistentEntities.java:95) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.wrap(PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.java:72) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.toResource(PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.java:55) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.AbstractRepositoryRestController.entitiesToResources(AbstractRepositoryRestController.java:110) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.AbstractRepositoryRestController.toResources(AbstractRepositoryRestController.java:80) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.lambda$toResource$1(RepositorySearchController.java:209) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.toResource(RepositorySearchController.java:206) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.executeSearch(RepositorySearchController.java:190) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at com.whateat.reciper.security.SimpleCORSFilter.doFilter(SimpleCORSFilter.java:35) [classes/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:117) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:106) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_201]
```

EndPoint 
http://localhost:8085/v1/places/search/findAllDistinctPlaceName

Comment: Could you please share the full stack trace and mark the exact call in the code you shared which triggers the exception?

Comment: I added the stack trace and the call.

Comment: you are having any entity like place?

Comment: result.add((String)o.getName()); i think it work

Comment: This is not coming from the code you posted but from Spring Data Rest. I don't think Spring Data Rest supports String and similar as return type. See the somewhat related issue https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-841

Comment: Place is an entity

Answer (score 9):

You tried to use SDR's default endpoints for your query.
But those endpoints can return only persistentEntities (or collection of PersistentEntities), because SDR wraps the response into a Resource object. (eg. adding the selfLink to the response, handling pagination etc.)

But your response is a List, so the ResourceAssembler cannot process it.

If you really want to use SDR for handling this endpoint maybe you can extend the ResourceAssembler some way, but I think that's a bad idea and probably wouldn't worth the effort.

Instead create a unique controller with the appropriate method, call the repository method from there and create the response Resource object manually.